# Duplication of indicator applets on panel after suspend on LXDE

Tags: suspend, indicator, lxde, lxpanel

I am using Lubuntu 16.04 and after every suspend some of my indicator applets are duplicated, so that for example after seven suspends my panel looks like this:

[image: lxpanel with too many indicators]

How can I avoid this or repair it?

Comment: does 'lxpanelctl restart' clear it out?

Comment: Yes, it helps for several suspends, but in some time it appears again. Also I open "Indicator applets" settings and turn off and on "Indicator application" checkbox, but it also helps only for several suspends